# Adding a network folder to PHP

Tags: php, networking, copy, move

I have this code that takes the files from $sDirectory and opens each one of them, then reads each line of the TXT and if it contains $Word in each line, it copies the file to $NewDirectory and $NewDirectory2 , my question is: How can I assign one of the new directories to be a network folder? f.e "\\10.55.33.14\Folder".

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$sDirectory     = 'C:\Users\ramosala\Desktop\New folder (2)';
$sNewDirectory  = 'C:\Users\ramosala\Documents\Prueba Coppel 2';
$sNewDirectory2 = 'C:\Users\ramosala\Documents\Prueba Coppel';
$Word="/\b(rfc        = COP-920428Q20)\b/i";
if( !is_dir( $sNewDirectory ) )
{
    mkdir( $sNewDirectory, 0777, TRUE );
}
if( !is_dir( $sNewDirectory2 ) )
{
    mkdir( $sNewDirectory2, 0777, TRUE );
}
$sFilter = '12';
if( is_dir( $sDirectory ) ) 
{
    $rDir = opendir( $sDirectory );
    while( ( $sFile = readdir( $rDir ) ) !== FALSE ) 
    {
        if( ( $sFile == '.' ) || ( $sFile === '..' ) )
        {
            continue;
    }
    $sFilePath = $sDirectory . '/' . $sFile;
    $sContents = file_get_contents( $sFilePath );
    $Line = $sContents;
if (preg_match($Word,$Line)){
    if( strpos( $sContents, $sFilter ) !== FALSE )
    {
        $sNewFileName  = $sNewDirectory . '/' . $sFile;
        $sNewFileName2 = $sNewDirectory2 . '/' . $sFile;
        if( !copy( $sFilePath, $sNewFileName ) || !copy( $sFilePath, $sNewFileName2 ) )
        {
            echo 'Could not move: ' . $sFile;
        }
        else
        {
            unlink( $sFilePath );
        }
    }
}
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I guess the most important question is under which protocol are you going to access remote host.

Comment: Maybe... actually try using the UNC path?

Comment: Use the windows computername path \\mystoragepc\storefolder\/ for folders you sometimes need to add a trailing / for windows.

Comment: I've tried with these two solutions and it appears me the legend "failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\AppServ\www\MovimientoPrueba3.php on line 34"